# 'Element' is imported from 2 packages

Tags: android, dart, flutter

i'm trying to use html parsing with dart in a Flutter App:

```
Future getSomething() async {

  http.Response response = await http.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/');

  Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

  document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach((Element element){
  print(element.text);
  });
}
```

But i have an error in `(Element element)` :

> Compiler message:
>   lib/main.dart:7:1: Error: 'Element' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' and 'package:html/dom.dart'.

Comment: The Element class is present in the html/dom package and in the flutter package. Place this method in a separate file and in this new file do NOT import the flutter packages, only the html/dom package.

Comment: are you sure  that the request http.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/') work for the httpS site ? 
please make sure that you have the full html before manipulate it

Comment: @MoxGeek its working

Comment: @Feu Thank you.. please add an answer it will help others.. if not i can do it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can hide `Element` from the flutter import:

`import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' hide Element`;

You can also use alias:

`import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as widgets`;

Comment: thank you, i fixed it next to : `import 'package:flutter/material.dart'hide Element;`