# Flutter update causing errors for packages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I recently updated my flutter version to the latest version and now im getting package dependency errors that i've never seen before after running the app.

Stacktrace:
[image]

Comment: for null error refer here to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918535/the-library-packageflutter-mobile-vision-flutter-mobile-vision-dart-is-legacy/68918873#68918873 and for the import error you should name one of the imports: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815020/element-is-imported-from-2-packages

Comment: It seems pretty clear in the stacktrace what you need to fix I think

Answer (score 0):

Switch to stable channel in Flutter.

```
flutter channel stable
```

Also, don't forget to upgrade flutter after switching channel.

```
flutter upgrade
```